# Java 8 modify instance from iteration

Tags: java, java-8, stream

How can we do this in java 8?

```
    void modifyInstances(final List<A> elements) {
        for (A a : elements) {
            a.setName("name");
            a.setAge(19);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use `forEach` but I don't see the point of changing that code.

Comment: You can just use it the way you do in java 7.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
elements.forEach(x -> {
   x.setName("name");
   x.setAge(19);  
})
```

but what you have in place is cleaner IMO, so why change it?